# Find the parameter values satisfying conditions for all roots of an equation

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

Hi I'm very new at Mathematica.

My real problems concerns a much more difficult equation with many parameters, but I want to check that the method is good, so I made up a test equation.

My test equation and roots:

```
equ = (5 x^3 + z + x z + x^2 (1 + z) == 0)  
sol = x /. Solve[equ, x]
```

Here is problem. I'm looking to the parameter `z` such that all the roots of the equation are less than zero (edit: real parts less than 0, where, `z` is a real number and the roots can be complex:

```
Reduce[Re[sol[[1]]] < 0 && Re[sol[[2]]] < 0 && Re[sol[[3]]] < 0 && Im[z] == 0, z]
```

The answer is (I think) `z > 4`, but the function `Reduce` doesn't calculate this in a reasonable time. How do I proceed?

---

EDIT after few days:
In equation with more  parameters:

```
equ=-11.8193 + 12.0482 b - 59.0964 x + 12.0482 a x - 11.8193 d x + 12.0482 b d x + 0.320482 x^2 + 12.0482 c x^2 - 59.0964 d x^2 + 12.0482 a d x^2 + 1. x^3 + 0.320482 d x^3 + 1. d x^4 
Reduce[ForAll[x, equ == 0 \[And] Element[{a, b, c, d}, Reals], Re[x] < 0], {a, b, c, d}]
```

It is good code? I waiting and waiting for a response from the Mathematica.

Maybe it would be faster if the program could write only one/few numerical answer?

Comment: If the roots can be complex, what do you mean they are less than zero ?

Comment: I mean that Real parts of all roots must be less than 0.

Comment: Just to show how to formulate this with `Reduce`:  `Reduce[ForAll[x, 5 x^3 + z + x z + x^2 (1 + z) == 0, x < 0], z, Reals]`.  This is very fast.  If you allow complex `z` and `x`, it takes longer than I cared to wait.  (When you write these expressions, keep in mind that in Mathematica `x<0` implicitly implies that `x` is real.  This is important if you remove `Reals` from `Reduce` but keep `x<0` instead of `Re[x]<0`)

Comment: Another note: if Reduce seems to hang on inequalities, there's reason to believe that it won't finish in any reasonable time.  I remember people commenting that it uses an algorithm called cylindrical algebraic decomposition, which has a "bad" complexity in the number of variables.  Please google for details if you're interested, I don't want to give you incorrect information and I am not familiar with this kind of mathematics.

Comment: Following @Szabolcs idea, `Reduce[ForAll[x, 5 x^3 + z + x z + x^2 (1 + z) == 0 \[And] Im[z] == 0,
   Re[x] < 0], z, Complexes]` gives the solution immediately.

Comment: @Thies Good idea to allow complexes, but look for real `z` only!  Why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: Ok, i'll post it then!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Finding the whole solution set**

Inspired by @Szabolcs idea, you can let `Reduce` solve this problem with the help of existential quantifiers:

```
Reduce[ ForAll[x, 5 x^3 + z + x z + x^2 (1 + z) == 0 \[And] Im[z] == 0, Re[x] < 0], z]
```

It immediately affirms your conjecture:

```
(* z > 4 *)
```

This problem formulation via `ForAll` can be read as:
`Reduce` the following statement with respect to `z` over the complex numbers: 
"For all `x` that satisfy the condition that `5 x^3 + z + x z + x^2 (1 + z) == 0` where `z` is restricted to the real number line, the real part of `x` is negative."

**Finding a numeric solution**

If you are not so much interested in all possible solutions but just one that meets certain criteria, you can use `NMinimize` to help solve that optimization problem. For that to work smoothly it's useful to set up some helper functions first:

```
PolyRoots[poly_, paramrules : {(_ -> _?NumericQ) ..}] :=
  x /. {ToRules@NRoots[poly /. paramrules, x]}
```

This takes a polynomial and a list of rules which specify the parameters and their values and returns a list of all roots. The big obfuscated looking pattern match has the purpose of making sure that the function definition fires only when the right hand side of all rules (`a -> 123`) assumes numeric values.

To make it easier for `NMinimize` to get an idea how bad the current set of parameter values is, we introduce a function that assigns a penalty value to a set of parameter values based on the sum of the squares of the real parts of all roots if they are positive and zero if they are negative. That allows `NMinimze` to "sense" it's way to better solutions until it hits the promised land, where solutions have penalty value zero.

```
Penalty[poly_, paramrules : {(_ -> _?NumericQ) ..}] :=
  Total[HeavisideTheta[#] #^2 & @ Thread @ Re @ PolyRoots[poly, paramrules]]
```

The final step is setting up the polynomial (including a cosmetic change of variable names so that the variables in our final solution have the desired names) and letting `NMinimize` do the work:

```
Module[{poly},
  poly = -11.8193 + 12.0482 b - 59.0964 x + 12.0482 a x - 
    11.8193 d x + 12.0482 b d x + 0.320482 x^2 + 12.0482 c x^2 - 
    59.0964 d x^2 + 12.0482 a d x^2 + 1. x^3 + 0.320482 d x^3 + 
    1. d x^4 /. {a -> aa, b -> bb, c -> cc, d -> dd};
  {penalty, solution} = 
  NMinimize[
    {Penalty[poly, {aa -> a, bb -> b, cc -> c, dd -> d}], a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0},
    {a, b, c, d}]
 ]

(* {0., {a -> 13.2852, b -> 7.3045, c -> 2.38894, d -> 0.171584}} *)
```

Comment: You don't even need to specify the domain as `Complexes`, as that's the default.  Nice and +1!

Comment: Ah nice, that simplifies the solution even more!

Comment: This gets a vote. I'm kinda' embarrassed now by the things I tried.

Comment: @Thies Heidecke 
What do you think about this:
equ=-11.8193 + 12.0482 b - 59.0964 x + 12.0482 a x - 11.8193 d x + 
 12.0482 b d x + 0.320482 x^2 + 12.0482 c x^2 - 59.0964 d x^2 + 
 12.0482 a d x^2 + 1. x^3 + 0.320482 d x^3 + 1. d x^4
    Reduce[ForAll[x, equ == 0 \[And] Element[{a, b, c, d}, Reals], 
  Re[x] < 0], {a, b, c, d}] 
?

Comment: @user5851 I think in principle the method should work here too, although with those four parameters you probably get an explosion of cases that `Reduce` has to enumerate. Do you know more about the possible values of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, like additional constraints or ranges of values? That could help `Reduce` get the number of cases down. Also what's the origin of that problem? Maybe there is another way of solving that problem.

Comment: @Thies Heidecke I Suppose that the values ​​of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` will be greater than or equal to 0 Some solutions will be in the range 0-1000, but it is possible that, for example, `d = 0.03`.
For the case above: 
'equ = -11.8193 + 12.0482 b - 59.0964 x + 12.0482 a x - 11.8193 d x + 12.0482 b d x + 0.320482 x^2 + 12.0482 c x^2 - 59.0964 d x^2 +  12.0482 a d x^2 + 1. x^3 + 0.320482 d x^3 + 1. d x^4'
Solution satisfying me is when parameters will be equal to:
 
    'In[30]:= Solve[(equ /. {a -> 100, b -> 10, c -> 10, d -> 10}) == 0, x]'

Comment: Out[30]= {{x -> -0.113833 - 34.0255 I}, {x -> -0.113833 + 34.0255 I}, {x -> -0.096408 -0.00954802 I}, {x -> -0.096408 +  0.00954802 I}}
And this is the origin of the problem. But I've got a little more complicated, but very similar to this problem that I can't find even a single solution.

Comment: For 2 parameters:
`equ = equ /. {a->100, d -> 10}` 
`FindInstance[ForAll[x, equ == 0 \[And] Element[{b, c}, Integers], Re[x] < 0], {b, c}]` give solution in few seconds.
For 3 parameters
 `equ = equ /. {a->100}` 
`FindInstance[ForAll[x, equ == 0 \[And] Element[{b, c, d}, Integers], Re[x] < 0], {b, c, d}]` Don't have solution after few hours...

Comment: Is that some kind of optimization problem? Because then maybe there are better ways to find good solutions (`NSolve` / `NMinimize`). Trying to map out the whole solution space will produce a huge answer and probably this is why `Reduce` and `FindInstance` take so long.

Comment: Thies Heidecke, I editing your answer to simplify the pattern in the definitions.  Also, your chosen line break point (starting a line with `:=`) is invalid in copy&paste so I corrected it.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! i knew there must be a more elegant way to express that pattern.

Answer (score 4):

```
RegionPlot[ And @@ Thread[(Re[sol /. z -> (a + b I)]) < 0], {a, 3, 10}, {b, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

As per your edit, `z` is Real (really bad choice for a name), so:

```
Plot[Re[sol], {z, -1, 10}, Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that from z==4 onwards, the two complex conjugate solutions are negative, as well as the real one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think the plot will not work, if I have for example 3 parameters in the equation.

Comment: @user5851 I think there is no universal answer/method to your problem, as it may end up with almost any set of inequalities in the general case. This is just an example for your toy problem. It may be useful if you try to describe your actual equations.